# GoLang Query Error: expected slice but got struct

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to Golang so i don't know how to change my code to fix this.

Error: expected slice but got struct

Ive looked up slices and researched them i'm just stuck as to how to adjust my struct into a slice and other things that i may need to change.

My Code is below any help would be greatly appreciated

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type Tag struct {
    Stream_count     string `json:"stream_count"`
    Query_desc       string `json:"Query_Desc"`
    Query_start_date string `json:"Query_start_date"`
    Query_end_date   string `json:"Query_end_date"`
    Current_date     string `json:"Current_date"`
    Error_info       string `json:"Error_Info"`
}

type CachedTag struct {
    Tag
    expireAtTimeStamp int64
}

var cache = map[string]CachedTag{}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "*******")

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        log.Print("Error Connecting to DB")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    date_1 := r.FormValue("date_1")
    date_2 := r.FormValue("date_2")
    time_1 := r.FormValue("time_1")
    time_2 := r.FormValue("time_2")

    if data, ok := cache[date_1+date_2]; ok {
        Now := time.Now().Unix()
        if Now < data.expireAtTimeStamp {
            j, err := json.Marshal(data.Tag)
            log.Print("Checking Expiry Date")
            if err != nil {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                w.Write([]byte((err.Error())))
                log.Print("Caching error")
                return
            }
            log.Print("Caching Success")
            w.Write(j)
            return
        }
    }
    var tag Tag

    err = db.Select(&tag, "SELECT SUM(duration) FROM sessions WHERE (app_id = '*****' OR app_id ='*****' OR app_id ='*****' OR app_id ='*****'OR app_id ='*****') AND date(created ) between ? and ? and time(created ) between ? and ? AND (`media_src`='*****' OR `media_src`='*****' OR `media_src`='*****' OR `media_src`='*****'  OR `media_src`='*****'  OR `media_src`='*****') GROUP BY date(created)", date_1, date_2, time_1, time_2)
    // if err != nil {
    //  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    //  w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    //  panic(err.Error())
    // }
    log.Print(tag.Stream_count)

    tag.Query_desc = "Listener Hours"
    tag.Query_start_date = date_1
    tag.Query_end_date = date_2
    dt := time.Now()
    tag.Current_date = dt.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05")
    if err != nil {
        tag.Error_info = err.Error()
    }
    ct := CachedTag{}
    ct.Tag = tag
    ct.expireAtTimeStamp = time.Now().Unix() + 1000
    cache[date_1+date_2+time_1+time_2] = ct

    j, err := json.Marshal(tag)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte((err.Error())))
        return
    }
    w.Write(j)

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/database/querying#single_row - use `db.QueryRow` to get single row.

Answer (score 1):

db.Select() returns rows, i.e. an array (or slice).
So you should use either:

```
  var tags []Tag
  err := db.Select(&tags, "SELECT ...")
```

or you should use

```
  var tag Tag
  err := db.Get(&tag, "SELECT ...")
```

The latter should be used for queries expecting only 0..1 rows in the result while select expects 0..N and you must check the length of the slice on return.

Comment: Tried this but got a new error: missing destination name Sum in *[]main.Tag Any idea how to fix this?